# How to include and use chacha from openssl library

Tags: c, security, openssl, cryptography

I would like to use chacha cipher from openssl library, I include it as

`#include <openssl/crypto/include/internal/chacha.h>`

However get this error:

> fatal error: openssl/crypto/include/internal/chacha.h: No such file or directory

I use linux and have openssl-dev installed, when building I use flags -lssl and -lcrypto.
Am I missing anything?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The latest version of Openssl is 1.1.1c If you are using an old version it will not include chacha.

Comment: @OP What does the word _internal_ suggest you?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I hoped to get enlightened here from more experienced people.

Comment: @uduck Well, it means it is not part of the accessible functionality. I would suggest starting here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

Comment: Use EVP_chacha20() as documented here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_chacha20.html, in conjunction with the information in the link provided by @LorinczyZsigmond.

Comment: @MattCaswell, thanks, I totally overlooked EVP_chacha20().

Comment: I think starks initial comment says it best. Sure, maybe that file is *meant* to be internal, but it should exist in newer versions. If you don't find it you have either not downloaded it or you are pointing the pre-compiler to the wrong location (mostly the system provided source code vs downloaded source code in a local directory). And yeah, that EVP function will probably not exist without it (I presume it was added with the implementation - especially since it is fast in software - although in theory it could be provided by an OpenSSL engine, of course).

Comment: Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.